# Error connecting to POP mailbox using OAuth and Java

Tags: java, office365

Does anyone know if Java Mail 1.6.2 supports OAuth authentication for POP3 protocol?  If so are you able to point me to documentation that confirms this?  I've looked online for a long time for confirmation but to no avail.

I cannot seem to get a successful connection to a POP mailbox using the client_credentials grant type using the javax mail 1.6.2 library.

Thanks for anyone taking time to respond.

Bret